# In an Azure Mobile App Services client, how do I set the userId so loginAsync works?

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm implementing custom authentication in a Xamarin.Forms app that uses a .NET backend in Azure, some of the controllers are marked with [Authorize].  I've followed instructions from a multitude of blogs and articles, but it's still unclear how to make TableController calls that are unauthorized trigger a login screen, or how to access the same authentication subsystem loginAsync does to set the userId or token information so that multiple instances of MobileServiceClient retains the latest userId and MobileServiceAuthenticationToken values.  How do I correctly trigger a login page and update the userId / token in the same authentication subsystem MobileServiceClient accesses with the other OOTB providers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your mobile app tries to access a backend that is marked with [Authorize], but an authorization header is not provided (technically, an X-ZUMO-AUTH header with a valid JWT), the service returns 401 Unauthenticated. There are a number of ways to trap this, but your operation will fail (and in a Xamarin.Forms application, that will cause a MobileServiceInvalidOperationException).  You need to handle this case, call loginAsync() and then re-try the operation.

You should not have multiple MobileServiceClients - you should have one at a global scope (use DI to inject it or just make it a static in the App context).  The MobileServiceUser will be used by all tables that are generated.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer on this for months.  What is the best approach to trap the MobileServiceInvalidOperatiomException?  I was thinking about creating a custom attribute to decorate [Secured] functions or classes using something like PostSharp so I can keep the authentication code in one place. Another method I've seen is a DelegatingHandler to replace authentication altogether by proxying responses and manually adding the X-ZUMO-AUTH header (a la CofeeCups by James Montemagno).  Do you have a recommended method for trapping status 401 and calling loginAsync?

Comment: My recommendation is to make login explicit.  I have an icon in the UI that calls the loginAsync() when I click on it.